# i have implemented merge sort in c++. it has no errors but somehow it doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mergesort

below given is the merge sort implementation in c++. I have used visual studio code. it takes the input but then just stops without showing any error. I think it might have segmentation fault somewhere but I'm not able to figure it out.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int beg, int mid, int end) //function to merge the arrays
{
int i = beg;
int j = mid +1;
int k, index = 0;
int temp[100];
while(i <= mid && j <= end)
{
    if(arr[i] < arr[j])
    {
        temp[index] = arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        temp[index] = arr[j];
        j++;

    }
    index++;
}
while(i <= mid)
{
    temp[index] = arr[i];
    i++;
    index++;
}

while(j <= end)
{
    temp[index] = arr[j];
    j++;
    index++;
}

for(int k = beg; k < index; k++)
    arr[k] = temp[k];
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int beg, int end)  //dividing the array
{
int mid = (beg + end)/2;
mergeSort(arr, beg, mid);
mergeSort(arr, mid+1, end);

merge(arr, beg, mid, end);
}

int main(void)
{
int arr[100];
cout<<"enter the array"<<endl;

 int size = sizeof(arr);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cin>>arr[i];


mergeSort(arr, 0, size-1);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout<<arr[i];
}
```

Comment: If the code compiles - it doesn't mean that it works correctly. Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Learn a debugger.

Comment: There must be at least one path through a recursive function that doesn't recurse.

Comment: `int size = sizeof(arr);` is wrong when sizeof int is not 1. Here is an example showing that: https://ideone.com/2QM9JJ

Answer (score 5):

Your recursive `mergeSort` function is causing stack to overflow as there is no termination condition in your function. The function is recursive on all paths. It is the case of infinite recursion where the function doesn't ever return and keeps calling itself endlessly resulting in stack overflow. Change the function type, use the conditional statement and return where appropriate.

Comment: okay thanks. got it to work.